# Please explain to me the meaning of the sentence below

Tags: meaning

From an [Op-Ed piece](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/13/opinion/when-the-state-of-the-union-is-strong-but-doesnt-feel-like-it-is.html?_r=0) by Bryce Covert in *The New York Times* (1/13/16)

[But as president, Mr. Obama gets to take time to crow about what’s good in the economy, not just focus on fixing what’s bad, as nearly all candidates of both parties are doing.]  It's a tricky line to work and a nearly impossible one on the campaign trail, because, according to recent polls, voters mostly feel that the economy still has a way to go until they will personally feel financially secure.

Comment: Please clarify.  What is it that you don't understand?  The first phrase (tricky line....)?  Also, context needed.

Comment: Well, "still hass a way to until" is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost impossible to give an answer to the question that you've asked, because you've left out the most important part of the quotation; the part that provides the context. (And when asking for an explanation of a quote you should always say where your quote comes from so that anyone who answers has a context for the question.) In this case it's from a [New York Times editorial](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/01/13/opinion/when-the-state-of-the-union-is-strong-but-doesnt-feel-like-it-is.html) about the State Of The Union address delivered by President Obama, and the upcoming primary elections for the two main parties. The full quote is:

> ... as president, Mr. Obama gets to take time to crow about what’s
>   good in the economy, not just focus on fixing what’s bad, as nearly
>   all candidates of both parties are doing. It’s a tricky line to walk
>   and a nearly impossible one on the campaign trail, because, according
>   to recent polls, voters mostly feel that the economy still has a way
>   to go until they will personally feel financially secure.

What the editorial is saying is that Obama, as the incumbent president, can talk about both good and bad things in the economy. He has more scope to talk about good things, and a greater desire to do so, because of course he wants to be able to claim credit for them for his administration. ***However*** he is aware that many ordinary American voters do ***not*** feel that everything is good in the economy. They don't feel secure about their jobs, they don't feel secure about their future.

Consequently if all Obama did was to crow about how good things are, those people would tune out. They would feel that he was not aware of, or didn't care about their problems and concerns. He would lose their support, and lose their votes for his party. Therefore he needs to recognise that there are things which are ***not*** good in the economy, and which need fixing. If he overemphasises the things that are wrong, though, he just gives ammunition to the opponents of his party for the next election.

He therefore has to "work" this "tricky line" between overstating the good things in the economy (and therefore losing the support of those who don't feel that things are good for them), and overstating the bad things that still need to be fixed (which would reflect badly on the competence of his administration).

The people who are running for president, on the other hand, want to emphasise the things that need fixing since they want the voters to elect them to fix them. However they also have to "walk a line" between that negativity, and ***some*** recognition of the good things in the country. If they don't, they risk voters thinking that they're too negative.

The balance between those two is indeed "a tricky line", both for incumbent governments, and for those seeking election.